# how to start activity on ribbon menu android

Tags: android, menu, ribbon

I am using [this project](https://github.com/danieltwagner/LibSlideMenu) as a reference.

When i click on ribbon menu items toast are displayed.
How to start an activity on this or how to set content dynamically and displayed accordingly(like in facebook).

```
public void onSlideMenuItemClick(int itemId) {
    switch(itemId) {
    case R.id.item_one:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item one selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, newjava.class)); //this generate error and forcing the app to close.
        break;
}
```

LogCat as soon as i click on item

```
12-06 02:41:32.857: D/AndroidRuntime(2967): Shutting down VM
12-06 02:41:32.857: W/dalvikvm(2967): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a2ab90)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967): Process: com.coboltforge.slidemenuexample, PID: 2967
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.coboltforge.slidemenuexample/com.coboltforge.slidemenuexample.newjava}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at com.coboltforge.slidemenuexample.MainActivity.onSlideMenuItemClick(MainActivity.java:75)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at com.coboltforge.slidemenu.SlideMenu$1.onItemClick(SlideMenu.java:367)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-06 02:41:32.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2967):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What error? Post log cat.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to manifest file with your Different **Activity** name: because of name of Activity problem occurs...

```
<activity
    android:name="com.coboltforge.slidemenuexample.yourActivityname" >
</activity>
```

Comment: issue resolved.
try to change the intent-filter, getting error at console "ActivityManager: Error type 3"

clean the project. works fine..

Anyways Thank you sir.

Comment: sir btw do you have any idea how to open the contents on the same activity ?
just like Facebook app where the contents dynamically change when we click on ribbon items.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention the Activity in Manifest file...Add this to your manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.coboltforge.slidemenuexample.newjava" >
</activity>
```

Comment: **{com.coboltforge.slidemenuexample/com.coboltforge.slidemenuexample.newjava}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?** clearly saying that you missed declaring

Comment: Sir i am working with two files both are added in manifest.
I know generally its a file missing in manifest error but now i am clueless.